# Header - show title in the middle of two buttons

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I need two menu buttons in my header. Unfortunately the Hamburgermenu doesn't move to the left. It currently looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button menuToggle start>
        <ion-icon class="fa fa-bars" style="color:red;"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="presetActionSheet()">
        <ion-icon class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" style="color:red;"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      <ion-icon class="fa fa-tachometer"></ion-icon>
      {{'vocables.headerTitle' | translate}}
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it as shown below.

**Note:** You need to use `menuToggle left` and no need to use `<ion-buttons start>`

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle left>
        <ion-icon class="fa fa-bars" style="color:red;"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="presetActionSheet()">
        <ion-icon class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" style="color:red;"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      <ion-icon class="fa fa-tachometer"></ion-icon>
      {{'vocables.headerTitle' | translate}}
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```